# Timeout error on saving processes after upgrading Webcon

Tags: sql-server, webcon

We have a problem with Webcon BPS (after upgrading from 2017_1_3.540 to 2017_1_3.665) runing on SharePoint 2013 Foundation web app.
After saving processes in BPS Designer Studio we have a timeouts from content database where elements are writing.

- Running on SQL Server 2016.
- BPS_Content weighs 231GB and BPS_Content_Att weighs 740GB.
- Server has 4vcores 2.30GHz and 16GB RAM, databases and logs are on a different disks.

We know that this is because the large database and low performance of SQL Server. But, is there any way to get better performance from a server configuration way? Or optionally increase timeouts for saving elements from Designer Studio to database?

We've read a lot of articles, but still SQL Server is weakest performance point of the infrastructure.